# Any reason to serialize an object stored in a session variable?

Tags: php, session, object

Is there any reason to serialize an object stored in a $_SESSION variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it happens automatically when you save the session anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If your session is auto-started, you have to resort to pretty ugly hacks to load the class definitions beforehand so the object can be properly unserialized. In this case, unserializing by hand is preferable. Of course, in this case, not auto-starting the session is even more preferable.

Comment: Just for clarification, the hacks you're referring to are required because sessions are usually started before the framework has a chance to bootstrap. So things like the autoloader and classes stored in session aren't available yet. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, because classes aren't loaded by the time the session is started.